# Override .objects in Model Django outside models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to override Classes in `models.py` to get call stacks at runtime.

I know that we can do following in Django in order to override manager and hence customize QuerySet API -

So, in `models.py`

```
class A(models.Model):
      objects = SomeClass()
```

and in `SomeClass`

```
class B(Manager):
     def get_query_set(): 
     # override the way you want
```

But, in order to make things simpler I am thinking to use decorator to override the same - So, 
in `models.py`

`@ decoratorForOverriding
class A(models.Model):
    pass`

in `decorator.py`

```
def decoratorForOverriding(cls):
 cls.objects = SomeClass()
```

Error I get is

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Any idea what is going on?
Should I make the `class A` as an abstarct class? That did not do the trick either.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A decorator must returns something. Here it should returns the modified class.

Comment: Also beware that there is quite some balck magic happening involved in django models classes (cf `django.models.base.ModelBase`, specifically the `__new__()` method), so your naive solution will very probably not work as is.

Comment: @JérômeThiard Tried doing that too. I also tried updating with `update.wrapper` from `functools` so that the class attributes may stay the same. But it creates issues regarding `Foreign Keys`.  
@brunodesthuilliers , Yes, I just do not understand where to get those "ALL" insights. Can you please point me to the link where and how to access `django.models.base.ModelBase` data.(Ex. get class attributes of theModelBase, use it outside, and return the same attributes so that the returned one would" behave" the desired way.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned that you were aware of how to override the `Manager` of a Model. I am having trouble imagining what the benefit of overriding the manager in a decorator vs as a property. as `bruno desthuilliers` mentions in his comment, Django does a bunch of stuff with the objects property at instantiation, the decorator probably will not work.

Do this the way Django core intended: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/

doing otherwise is going to add technical debt for no real benefit (at least as far as I can tell). If there is something that cannot be achieved through a `Manager` lets tackle that problem.

Comment: Francis Yaconiello, there is a huge existing django app, and I would like to get call stacks of classes in `models.py`, I may not want to log call stacks for all classes, may be some. So in existing code, to make things simpler for this so called as "Meta Task", I thought of using decorators which in turn will help me by not disturbing the existing code. My use case is - To get Call Stacks of desired classes in the django app on runtime. So, using decorators for such task is not desirable?